# a problem of failing to carry out all the repetitions

Tags: linked-list

**Problem**

My current implementation currently does not output all the results I expect to get. My current code, expected and actual result can be seen below.

**Task**

Print the indexes of the corresponding parentheses and leave the form without checking all the characters in the process of determining whether the parentheses are correct or wrong.

> args[0] = (3x((4+2)/2)-1)x(5-3)

```
        LinkedStack stack = new LinkedStack();
        LinkedStack stack2 = new LinkedStack();
        LinkedStack stack3 = new LinkedStack();

        for (int i = 0; i < args[0].length(); i++) {
            stack.push(args[0].charAt(i));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < stack.size(); i++) {
            if (stack.peek() == (Object) '(') {
                stack2.push(stack.size() - 1);
                stack.pop();
            } else if (stack.peek() == (Object) ')') {
                stack3.push(stack.size() - 1);
                stack.pop();
            } else {
                stack.pop();
            }
            if (stack2.size() == 1 && stack3.size() != 0) {
                System.out.println(stack2.pop() + "," + stack3.pop());
            }
        }
        if ((stack.size() == 0) && (stack2.size() != 0 || stack3.size() != 0)) {
            System.out.println("The parentheses are wrong.");

        } else {
            System.out.println("The parentheses are correct.");

        }
```

Expected result:

> 16,20
>
> 0,14
>
> 3,11
>
> 4,8
>
> The parentheses are correct.

Actual results:

> 16,20
>
> The parentheses are correct.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Could you clarify what you are asking? [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please provide the language you are using. [Minimal, complete and viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! I applied a bit of markup to your question and also phrased a question text that I think should fit. Please re-read the question text, add details that are currently missing. It's always good to start with the problem description and then add the details about your code. Also have a read at Andy's links he mentioned in his comment.